# why it is not possible to create an object with a reference name while adding an object in collection interface?

Tags: java

While adding an object with a reference name i am getting an error

```
class vechile
{
    void service()
    {
        System.out.println("Generic vehicle servicing");
    }
}

public class mechanic
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List vehicles = new ArrayList();
        vehicles.add(vechile q1=new vechile());// this line is showing error
        vehicles.add(new vechile());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the Java syntax doesn't allow it, because the Java designers decided it wasn't useful.

Comment: Note that in future questions, it really helps if you make the sample code follow normal naming conventions etc. (So `Vehicle` instead of `vechile`, and `Mechanic` instead of `mechanic`.) It's just less distracting that way.

Answer (score 5):

`vehicles.add(vechile q1=new vechile());` is not allowed.

You can do like this

```
vechile q1= null;
vehicles.add(q1=new vechile());
```

Answer (score 0):

In java or most of the OOP language when we add or put an element to an Array or List we are not passing the variable itself but only reference of that object so is it is irrelevant what ever the reference variable was. One has to create new reference type variable and then assign this object to it when we get the object from list.

```
 List vehicles = new ArrayList();
 //vehicles.add(vechile q1=new vechile());// Irrelavent
 vehicles.add(new vechile()); // Reference is added to the list and not the variable
         or
 vechile q1=new vechile()
 vehicles.add(q1);
```

And then when we get this objects from list first we have to create the reference type variable and then assign the object.

```
  Vehicle v1 = null;
  v1 = vehicles.get(i) //i is the index for q1.
```

Hence it is syntactically not allowed in java.

Hope I answered your question